# No network with HP ProLiant DL380 G5

Tags: networking, server, hp

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with my ProLiant. Here's the problem:

During installation, when it goes to configure the network, it detects my five network ports and the type of hardware for them just fine, but it can't get DHCP. I've checked the cable and router with other machines -- no problem there.

I've tried manually configuring the LAN ports with IP addresses, and that doesn't work either.

Any idea why it wouldn't be getting an address? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unplug the second nic from the switch/hub/router and let the auto discovery run.  Also make sure you aren't plugged into the iLo port otherwise I was building one today, make sure you run the Support pack to setup your raid and mirrors first THEN install the OS or the OS won't see the drives.